# Get specific files from MS Graph Sharepoint API

Tags: sharepoint

I'm using MS Graph API to get files from Sharepoint to show in a webapp.
My aim is to get all filenames and download-URL from files in a drive (with subfolders) that have a specific tag / value in a custom column.
Right now I'm getting all the children and can get all DownloadURL's , but I can't seem to filter by custom-column value. Also, I have to get all the children to filter the files.
This is taking much too long... (minutes)
So:

- Can I get only specific files (instead of using [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/search(q='')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/search(q=%27%27)) )
- Can I get downloadURL directly with fileinfo (using expand)?
- Can I filter files using 'filter' or '$filter' to get only the files with specific value in custom column?
  Thanks for sharing!
  Kind regards,
  Richard Kool

Get the files:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/search(q='')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/search(q=%27%27))
filter and expand do not work to filter only files, custom-column-values and downloadurl